# Make header photo 100% on smaller screens and mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress, width, fullscreen

I have this current Wordpress website: mypathway.com.au.

Apparently, it has been through a few different developers and every time some CSS has been added to it. In fact, there is css in the Theme Editor, in the Customise panel as well as in a plugin called Yellow Pencil. The Wordpress version is current version: 5.7.9 (we can't update for the time  being). The issue I'm having is that the main header photo in the home page doesn't remain 100% when it goes to a smaller screen or to the phone.

[Header doesn't stay full width on the right hand side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFX24.jpg)

I've used the Google Chrome inspector and the issue is that the element.style has a max-width set to pixels rather than 100%. When I update this in the inspector to max-width: 100%, it works but I can't figure out where I need to change this in the css, where, and what's the proper formatting. The element in question is this:

```
`<div data-vc-full-width="true" data-vc-full-width-init="true" class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid headerinsetshadow vc_custom_1687996767518 vc_row-has-fill vc_row-o-full-height vc_row-o-columns-stretch vc_row-o-equal-height vc_row-flex" style="position: relative; left: -360px; box-sizing: border-box; width: 1920px; max-width: 1920px; padding-left: 360px; padding-right: 360px; min-height: 43.3254vh;"><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12"><div class="vc_column-inner"><div class="wpb_wrapper"></div></div></div></div>`
```

I tried doing

```
.vc_custom_1687996767518{
width: 100% important; 
}
```

```
.vc_row .wpb_row .vc_row-fluid .headerinsetshadow .vc_custom_1687996767518 .vc_row-has-fill .vc_row-o-full-height .vc_row-o-columns-stretch .vc_row-o-equal-height .vc_row-flex{
width: 100% important;
}
```

Unfortunately, no luck.

Any insight and help would be greatly appreciated to see how it can be fixed.

Comment: your code is incorrect in one respect `<width: 100% important;` should read `<width: 100% !important;` _ with an exclamation in front of the word 'important'

Comment: There are some media queries for various screen sizes (including large) that are pulling the image all over the place, with negative values etc. You'll need to review those. They're embedded in the HTML pages, as you'll see by viewing the source code, or by checking the inspector.

Comment: @inputforcolor - Thanks for pointing that out, I think I just typed it incorrectly here as when I had a look on the site it was done correctly. But still, no change.

Hey there, thanks for your code but unfortunately it didn't work. I've also tried implementing !important to them but to no avail. 

It seems that the main issue is that it has the max-width set to px rather than % and for the life of me I can't find in which CSS file I can edit this.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Matt _  Just a thought but in future it's likely better to copy / paste code _ simply so that if there's an error there a fresh set of eyes might spot the something that's causing your headache_ but which you've missed _  Welcome to Stack Overflow btw ; )

Answer (score 0):

Here, See If This Works. Get back to me if its wrong. PLS

css

```css
<style>
img{
position:fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
min-width:100%;
max-width:100%;
min-height:100%;
max-height:100%
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hi there _ Welcome to Stack Overflow _  `img` is an html element NOT a class! You need to edit your question and remove the period mark in front = `.img` >>> `img`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @china Hey there, thanks for your code but unfortunately it didn't work. I've also tried implementing !important to them but to no avail. 

It seems that the main issue is that it has the max-width set to px rather than % and for the life of me I can't find in which CSS file I can edit this.